# First line from the paragh conversion

Tags: java, string

```
public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String paragh = "Twinkle, twinkle, little star\r\n"
                + "How I wonder what you are\r\n"
                + "Up above the world so high\r\n"
                + "Like a diamond in the sky\r\n"
                + "Twinkle, twinkle, little star\r\n"
                + "How I wonder what you are";
        
        String firstLine; // the first line should be derived from the paragh
        
    }

}
```

Now what should i do to make paragh's first line in the firstLine String?

Comment: Is every line always is separated by `\r\n` ?

Answer (score 2):

#### Option 1: `split`

Split the string by the `\r\n` delimiter with `paragh.split("\r\n")`. Then the first array element is the first line:

```java
String[] portions = paragh.split("\r\n", 2);
String firstLine = portions[0];
```

Note that we need only the first line. So one we have it, we don't need to look for more lines. That's why the second argument (`limit`) is set to 2.

#### Option 2: `indexOf` and `substring`

`indexOf` returns the first position the given substring is found. Once we have that index, we could return a portion of `paragh` from index 0 to that index:

```java
int pos = paragh.indexOf("\r\n");
if (pos != -1) {
    firstLine = paragh.substring(0, pos);
}
else {
    firstLine = paragh;
}
```

Note that `indexOf` returns the *sentinel value* `-1` if the substring `\r\n` was not found, i.e. when there's only one line. If there's only one line, then we could as well return the whole string.

---

<sup>Shorter versions of the code snippets:

• 1. `String firstLine = paragh.split("\r\n", 2)[0]`

• 2. `int pos = paragh.indexOf("\r\n"); String firstLine = (pos == -1 ? paragh : paragh.substring(0, pos));`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```java
String firstLine = paragh.split("\n")[0];
System.out.println(firstLine);
```